# Install Windows 7, keeping pre-installed Windows 8 (dual boot)?

Tags: operating-systems, windows-installation

I have a Samsung notebook with pre-installed Windows 8:
how can I install Windows 7 in dual boot?

I have read there might be some problems,
since Windows 8 runs on GPT partitions, and Windows 7 might have problems with activation.

NB: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/646805/dual-boot-windows-7-on-pre-installed-windows-8-laptop) question did not help, unfortunately

Comment: What're you really trying to achieve? You'd likely need to set the bios into legacy mode and such... and you're probably be better off running 7 on a VM.

Comment: this way, I would like to wipe the hard disk and install just Windows 7 from the scratch, hoping it would be possible without problems

Comment: As Journeyman Geek was saying, you may need to set the BIOS to legacy mode; youtu.be/WU7HpwzqbAg might help you with this issue. If you look in the expanded description of the video you can review everything that could potentially hamper the installation. If you need to disable UEFI from Advanced Settings (because you can't access your BIOS on startup), you can hold shift while you click restart and you'll be greeted by Advanced Settings. Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > UEFI Firmware Settings. Good luck!